# How can I easily keep track of enemy weaknesses?

Tags: radiant-historia

I've finally given that copy of *Radiant Historia* I bought a while ago a spin, and as I encounter more and more enemy types it becomes increasingly difficult to remember which enemy is vulnerable to which element.

Is there some sort of monster compendium I can access from somewhere that I am unaware of, or do I simply have to rely on my memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The White Chronicle](http://www.rhwiki.tk/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a small wiki dedicated to the game (with a [mirror here](http://radianthistoria.wikia.com/wiki/Radiant_Historia_Wiki)) is a good place to start, you can also check the [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/604160-radiant-historia/faqs) for the game as well. IGN also has a small [FAQs](http://www.ign.com/faqs/games/radiant-historia/nds-82067) page for it too.

Comment: While this is valid, I was hoping for something a little more in game, as I usually don't have convenient access to "teh internetz" when playing on my DS.

Comment: @Aubergine No, I don't recall anything in-game.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is a feature in the original game, but I know in Radiant Historia: Perfect Chronology you can press X in battle to see the enemies’ weaknesses and resistances.